# MQTT login fail

Tags: python, c#, authentication, mqtt

I'm trying to connect to a MQTT brooker to get data from my iot device.

For that, I'm basing myself on an exisitng python library that does exactly that with the exact brooker i need (user_id and key are provided before with and HTTP API authentication) :

```
def __init__
    mqtt_pass = generate_mqtt_password(user_id=self._cloud_creds.user_id, key=self._cloud_creds.key)
    self._mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(client_id=self._client_id, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
....
    self._mqtt_client.username_pw_set(username=self._cloud_creds.user_id, password=mqtt_pass)
    self._mqtt_client.tls_set(ca_certs=self._ca_cert, certfile=None,
                              keyfile=None, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                              tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS,
                              ciphers=None)

....
def generate_mqtt_password(user_id: str, key: str):
    """
    Generates the MQTT password that the APP uses to connect to the mqtt server.
    :param user_id:
    :param key:
    :return:
    """
    md5_hash = md5()
    clearpwd = f"{user_id}{key}"
    md5_hash.update(clearpwd.encode("utf8"))
    return md5_hash.hexdigest()
```

ref : https://github.com/albertogeniola/MerossIot/blob/07375049fc0cbc6adee2815b48fa639e74d0d946/meross_iot/manager.py

So I translated it to this in C#, using MQTTnet

```
var factory = new MqttFactory();
var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();


byte[] tmpSource = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(userId + key);
byte[] tmpHash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(tmpSource);

string passMd5 = BitConverter.ToString(tmpHash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();


// Create TCP based options using the builder.
var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
    .WithClientId(RandomString(32))
    .WithTcpServer("iot.meross.com", 2001)
    .WithCredentials(userId, passMd5)
    .WithProtocolVersion(MqttProtocolVersion.V311)
    .WithTls(new MqttClientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters()
    {
        UseTls = true,
        SslProtocol = SslProtocols.Tls12
    })
    .Build();

var result = await mqttClient.ConnectAsyn
```

However with my code It raise an exceptioin "Connecting with MQTT server failed (NotAuthorized)".

I've checked and the "password" I compute is exactly the same as the one the python code does.

Is there a difference I'm missing ?

Comment: Where are your certs in the C code?  I can see certs being defined in your Python code, but don't see them referenced in the MqttclientOptionsBuilderTlsParameters() function call?

Comment: The certfile property are set to non by default in the python code